# How to get relative path in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, path, relative-path

Whenever I right click on a file and hit 'Copy Relative Path' it gives me the correct path, but it always starts at src.

Lets say my folder structure is as follows (indent=new folder):

- src

  - components

    - component1
  - images

    - image1

If I am at the file image1, and I want to get the path to component1, how do I do this?

By this, I mean instead of getting the path 'src/components/component1' by copying the relative path, how do I get it in the format '../components/component1'?

I know I can do it manually, but the file structure is a bit complicated because this is a large project.

I tried navigating to the directory of the file I start at in terminal, but this did not work.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Extension [Context Menu Extra](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.context-menu-extra) v0.3.0 adds the `Copy Path relative to Active Editor` menu option to the context menu of the file explorer.

The result is stored in the Clipboard.

You have the option to add/remove the `./` in case you don't need to go `../`

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation

Comment: @AnonEemus If it solves the problem mark the answer as the solution